# Software upgrade solution in Solaris

Tags: solaris, upgrade, patch

I am working on developing an software.

I have installed the v1.0 on my machine running solaris 10,

and I want to upgrade to version 1.1 tha has some new function.

I do not want to uninstall version 1.0 but upgrade to version 1.1.

How do I make a patch?

Writing a script or using some patch tools?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about Solaris patches, i.e. those appling to SVR4 packages, I guess only Solaris engineering is able to build and deliver them as there is no standard/documented format I'm aware of. The new version of Solaris (11) is going to abandon this patching method anyway to the new pkg mechanism.

If you want a new version not to replace the older one, I guess the simplest way would be to have them to install in different directories. eg: /opt/zhangli/v1.0 and /opt/zhangli/v1.1. Any packaging format would support that.